# Can i render an image on a detached lcd screen of laptop with help of raspberry pi 3?

Tags: pi-2

I am new to raspberry.

What i want to do ?

I want to render an image on a (detached) lcd screen of a laptop with help of raspberry pi.

Questions :

1) Will it need hardware driver for lcd ?
2) Can I  display an image on this lcd screen without initiating raspbian os ?

If i am missing something in question please comment i will make it correct as soon as possible.

**What i have  researched :**

1.This is a video  about how to render videos on raspberry pie [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOHws0qBBmI)

2. I have gone through **question marked in "possible duplicate of" tag but it doesn't answer**  can we render without a driver or not , nither it gave any clarification weather we should write a code in raspi to render image pixel by pixel.

Comment: If you want to know how this site works you might want to [take a tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour). If want to improve your question. Please show us [what you have researched until now](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/64382/edit) your question and add the information.

Comment: Can I connect a random screen with no documentation to a Pi (or indeed anything else)? No. Neither have the hundreds of others who have asked similar questions.

Comment: Every answer for that duplicate question involves a controller of some sort, so yes, you will need one. Which one will work depends on the LCD you have.

Comment: thank you dmitry for some positive clue , so do you know about any stuff / code i should refer in order to render it ?

Comment: *"I have gone through question marked in "possible duplicate of" tag but it doesn't answer"* -> The basic point here is that the answer to the question in your title is **no**, you cannot -- there are likely people out there that *could*, but they would not bother because the time and trouble required simply make it not worthwhile.  It could take weeks or months of full time, skilled work.  No sane person would bother when they can buy a new screen appropriate to the task for a fraction of that cost.